# How to purposely throw an error to test database rollback?

Tags: java, exception, transactions, repository, rollback

I have the following code within my application:

```
try {
    //start transaction
    repository.startTransaction();

    //carry out deletion logic
    repository.deletedata()

    //commit all 3 transactions
    repository.commitTransaction();

} catch (Exception e) {    
    repository.rollback();
}
```

How can I intentionally throw an `error` within this code to test if the data is correctly being **rolled back**?

Comment: `throw new Exception("test exception");`

Comment: Use a `throw new Exception(...)` statement?

Comment: When I do this, below in my repository.commitTransaction(); method, I get "unreachable statement" compile error

Comment: Why would you want to throw an exception _after_ transaction commit? That makes no sense if you're trying to test transaction rollback. BTW if you get `unreachable statement`, then show the code that produces the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting testing wrong here.

You should be doing two things instead: you write a test that makes sure that your **rollback** method does what it promises to do. You test that on the side.

Then you have another **unit** test that simply makes sure that whenever there is an exception within your try block that the expected call to **rollback** takes place.

If you really want to do a **functional** test that does end-2-end testing including rollback, then you have to add some **injection** mechanism, something like:

```
interface ErrorInject {
  void throwException();
}
```

and in your try block, you would have something like:

```
try {
  repository.startTransaction();
  inject1.throwException();
  repository.deletedata()
  inject2.throwException();
  repository.commitTransaction();
}
```

and by default, those two "inject" objects simply do nothing; but for your test case, you make sure that one of those two objects really throws an exception.

But of course - you don't want to do something like that in your production code. So - you better step back and think if my first suggestion works for you.

One alternative could be **aspect oriented programming**; which might allow you to use some annotation for example to instruct your framework to  fail at a certain method call. But as said: you shouldn't pollute your production code with "testing aspects".